# Display Custom options of simple associated products in Configurable products of Magento

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have a few simple products with custom options defined for them in a Magento online shop. On the product view page, the custom options of the simple products are displayed and the page works as expected. When I associate those simple products with custom options for a configurable product, I want the custom options of the selected simple product need to be displayed on the view page. on changing the simple product in the dropdown, the custom options also need to be changed, just like the product price changes. And when adding the product to the cart, the custom options properties of the selected simple product also need to be appended to the configurable product property.

This seems to be somewhat complex. Please help me in getting this task done.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout out this extension [Simple Configurable Products Extension For Magento](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) by Organic.